# "I'm migrating to Australia" or "I'm immigrating to Australia"?

Tags: verbs, differences, synonyms, confusables

I am confused as to which is the correct way of saying

> I am migrating to Australia
>   OR
>   I am immigrating to Australia

Which one is appropriate?

Comment: immigrate = coming into a country; emigrate = going out of a country; migrate is for biological/group movements like animals, birds, electrons, population, statistical numbers.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, both forms are correct.

- *I'm migrating to Australia* means you are ***moving to*** that country.
- *I'm immigrating to Australia* means you are ***leaving*** your home country (often your birth-place) for Australia.

> **[migrate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/migrate?searchDictCode=all)** 2. (Of a person) move to a new area or country in order to find work or better living conditions: e.g: *Many villages in the regency are devoid of young people as they have **all migrated** to Medan, Jakarta, Surabaya and other urban areas due to a lack of jobs at home.*

To migrate is to *move* to a different location. If you migrate to a new city in your country of birth or residence, or ***move*** to a new country you will probably spend some time living in that place, in theory you *could* at any time migrate back home. This term is often used for animals (usually birds) that change their habitat according to the change in season.

> **[emigrate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/emigrate)** Leave one’s own country in order to settle permanently in another:
>   e.g: 
>   *First, skilled workers* **are legally emigrating**, *temporarily or
>   permanently, to rich countries.*

To  emigrate means to ***leave*** your country of origin for a different one. You don't normally say *emigrate* if you are leaving your village/town/city for a different city in your homeland. You usually emigrate to a different country. Once you have settled in your new home, you will probably be referred to as an ***immigrant***.

> **[immigrate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/immigrate)**  chiefly North American. Come to live permanently in a foreign country: e.g:
>   *Following this money, more than 1 million Taiwanese have* ***immigrated to*** *China to live and work.*

To immigrate means to ***come to*** a new country. The emphasis is on the destination, an *immigrant* is a person who lives in a different country from his birthplace or homeland.

<sup>Sources: Oxford Dictionaries and [Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/emigrate-immigrate-migrate/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct
However, they both mean different things

If you migrate to Australia, you are travelling to Australia to find better conditions than were you currently are located, usually on a temporary basis, with view to move back later.

If you immigrate to Australia, you are coming to settle here permanently/indefinately